# Get an item by index from the HashSet array and also display the average length of each item in the list

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I have created code that uses a HashSet array. I am brand new to Java programming and I would like to know how to accomplish these two tasks:

*Get an item by index from the HashSet array
*display the average length of each item in the list

My code isn't long at all so I am pasting the entire code here. Thanks for all your help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button aButton; // Global Scope
Button sButton;
TextView text2;
EditText eText;
HashSet<String> list = new HashSet<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout); 

    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //Clickable Saved Input will display alert
    text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            list.add("Books");
            list.add("Newspapers");
            list.add("Magazines");
            String listString = "";

            for (String s : list) {
                listString += s + " - ";
            }
            text2.setText(listString);
            }
        });




    sButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    eText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    sButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


             //Log.v("EditText", eText.getText().toString());
            if( !list.add(eText.getText().toString()) )
            {
                System.out.println("Not Unique Item");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else 
            {
                System.out.println("Unique Entry Added");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved To Items.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }

    });


    }

}
```

Comment: As the name suggests, a `HashSet` is a `Set` (a collection containing distinct (wrt. `equals`) elements *in no particular order*). If you want to store elements in a particular order and retrieve them by index, you'll have to maintain a `List` (e.g., an `ArrayList`) in addition to the `HashSet`.

Comment: And please use stringbuilder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Set is not what you want, because:

- Sets only hold *unique* values
- The elements of a Set have no order, so you can't access elements by index

A better choice is a List, such as an `ArrayList`, which allows any (ie duplicate) values and can be accessed by index using `list.get(i)`.

Comment: If I understand your answer, you're talking about generic Sets in both bullet items, right? If so, then there's a kind of set that has a "predictable iteration order": LinkedHashSet. Which could still bear the question: "Why can't one get the Nth element of an LHS directly, without iterating through N-1 elements?" The general contract of Sets is that any kind of ordering is not guaranteed so direct positional access could not be guaranteed. And I do agree with your suggestion on using lists.

Comment: @corindiano no, the billet points apply to both typed and untyped (ie raw) Sets. The contract (via javadoc) of LinkedHashSet only guarantees that *iteration* order is the same as *insertion* order. This is accomplished internally using a LinkedList rather than an ArrayList (hence the name *Linked*HashSet), which still doesn’t allow direct access to elements by index. BTW a LinkedList is used so the guarantee of all operations being completed in constant time may be upheld; ArrayList removal is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

HashSet should be used when you don't want to allow duplicate value in your collection. In HashSet you won't be able to find value by index. If you still want to find the element you have no other option but to use the iterator, it will iterate through the Hashset and give you one by one element from the Hashset.

You want to find your element by index you should use ArrayList.

There are two ways of iterating the HashSet -

```
HashSet <String> newset = new HashSet <String>();

 // populate hash set
      newset.add("A"); 
      newset.add("BB");
      newset.add("CCC");  

      // create an iterator
      Iterator iterator = newset.iterator(); 

      // check values
      while (iterator.hasNext()){
         System.out.println("Value: "+iterator.next() + " ");  
      }
```

Second approach is by using for loop-

```
for (String s : newset ) {
    System.out.println("Value: " +s);
}
```

Comment: Yes an iterator is what I am looking for. The problem is I have no idea how to create the code for it. Is it a long process? I tried google for references but I have not found many tutorials to accomplish this. Would you be able to help me?

Comment: There are two ways, see my updates ans.

Comment: Which way would Get 1 item by index from the HashSet array? I don't really care which one I just need to be able to get 1. Is it possible?

Comment: Try to use ArrayList, when you add item in array list than you can find item by index like you define ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>(); and than add the items in array list than you can find item by index like aa.get(indexvalue) ; indexvalue would be 0,1,2.....

Comment: For your reference - http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/07/difference-between-arraylist-hashset-in-java.html.   I hope it will help you .Difference between HashSet and ArrayList is that its index based you can retrieve object by calling get(index) or remove objects by calling remove(index) while HashSet is completely object based. HashSet also doesn't provide get() method.

Comment: Yes that would be the case for ArrayList. But what I really need to know (Even though it is better to use ArrayLists) is how to get 1 item from a HashSet. I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Comment: set.iterator().next(); it will return the first item but not maintain the same order as you add them in hashest.

Comment: I tried using your method but it did not work as expected. If you take a look at my code, you can se that my structure defines my HashSet outside the data collection. When I try to implement it it throws some erros and warnings. Does the iteration work when the HashSet array (In this case named "list") is outside the array elements? I constructed it this way because i needed to use the hash set array for more code below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62440/discussion-between-moni-and-user3078406).