# index of character in hashset Java

Tags: java, hashset

How do I get the index of element in HashSet when using java?

Let's say

```
HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();
hs.add('s');
hs.add('t');
hs.add('a');
hs.add('c');

// some code

if (hs.contains('a')) {
   int a = // need the index of a here from hashset 
}
```

The runtime for lookup has to be linear with any data structure.

Comment: `HashSet` is inherently unordered.  What do you mean by "index" here?  The position when the character was inserted?  Position based on some sort order?  Something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get an item by index from the HashSet array and also display the average length of each item in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185802/get-an-item-by-index-from-the-hashset-array-and-also-display-the-average-length)

Comment: convert to a List and use indexOf

Comment: According to [JavaDoc] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29)An implementation of  Set isn't required to maintain any order in the values.

Comment: You _could_ use `LinkedHashSet` here, which does maintain insertion order, but there is not any index of functionality from what I can see.

Comment: Use a `SortedSet` to have reliable sorting, convert it to a `List` and use `indexOf('a')`: `int a = new ArrayList<>(hs).indexOf('a');`

Comment: @Pulkit - what behaviour are you expecting if an element is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set does not have the index by definition. Instead, try to use something like HashMap. This would give you constant time for containsKey:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
hm.put('s',1);
hm.put('t',2);
hm.put('a',3);
hm.put('c',4);

// some code

if (hm.containsKey('a')){
int a = hm.get('a') //index is here

}
```

Comment: why would you use a Map rather than a List?

Comment: because containsKey is O(1) rather than O(n)

Comment: what would happen if you removed an element?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. Sure, if you remove 't', the index for 'a' won't become 2, but the question is do you need such property. In case of HashMap, delete operation also takes constant time, which might or might not be important for a particular use case. In case of lists, both delete and lookup by vaule take O(n) time comparing to O(1) for HashMap, but yes, a list would maintain the "correct" index.

Comment: basically what I am trying to do is find for closest duplicate in string, figured map or set is not the best way to go about it
For example, String s = "babab" with given index 2 // char b
closest is 0 and 4 
thus 0 being closest, I need to return 0

Comment: public static List<Integer> closest(String s, List<Integer> queries) {
    // Write your code here
        int min;
        int count = 0;
        List<Integer> ans = new List<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<queries.size(); i++){
            char a = s.charAt(i);
            for(int j=0; j<s.length(); j++){
                if(s[j] == a ){
                    int count = j;
                }else{
                    count = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: this is what I did so far

Comment: @vojislavdjukic can you help?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the problem: if I give you input (index 3, string "asdaa"), you program should find the closes 'a' from the index 3, and in this case, the result would be 4?

Answer (score 3):

The Set interface doesn't have something like as an `indexOf()` method. You'd really need to iterate over it or to use the List interface instead which offers an `indexOf()` method.

If you would like to, converting Set to List is pretty simple, it should be a matter of passing the Set through the constructor of the List implementation. E.g.

```java
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(nameSet);
```

Comment: The only downside to this is that the lookup time for `ArrayList#contains` now becomes linear, instead of constant time lookup for a map.  But, this is just how an array list works.

Comment: I am specifically wanting to stick to constant time for lookup

Answer (score 0):

A Set in unordered, so you cannot get an index from it. If you still want to get index from a set, you can opt for iterating through it.

```
HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();
Iterator it = hs.iterator();
int index =-1;
 while(it.hasNext()){
  i++;
  if(value.next()=='a'){
  return;
 }
}
return i== (hs.size()-1) ? -1 : i;
```

Constant time lookup will be traded off in this way because of unorderedness of HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` Class hasn't any functions to find the index of something inside it, So you can use something like `ArrayList` or `List`, But if you want to use `HashSet` any way, Then only way to find the item's index is by iterating it like:-

```
HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character();
hs.add('s');
hs.add('t');
hs.add('a');
hs.add('c');

int foundIndex = -1;

for(int i=0; i<hs.size(); i++){
    if(hs.get(i).equals('a')){
        foundIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if(foundIndex == -1){
    //The value wasn't in the HashSet
}else{
    int a = foundIndex;
    //The value was found
}
```

Comment: `foundIndex = i;` please break;

Comment: Thankyou for your comment but you know that `HashSet` hasn't any repeated value so this is not necessary only for reducing time this is necessary.

Comment: not necessary, but why loop through **all** elements after you have found the index?

Comment: Are you agree my answer now @ScaryWombat?